# CAS 4 - Not able to retrieve the LDAP groups after successful authentication

Tags: java, spring-security, ldap, cas

I have configured CAS 4 / Spring Security / Active Directory and able to authenticate successfully.

But I have difficulty in to retrieve roles and later use that for authorisation.

I have the roles available after the authentication in CAS but I want to pass this to the service (web app) so that it can be used to check the authorisation (for eg. hasRole('ROLE_EDITOR') )

I think I am making some configuration mistake in the below beans which I investigating further. I have shown these configuration fragments.

- bean 'casAuthenticationProvider' and the property 'authenticationUserDetailsService'
- bean 'ldapAuthenticationHandler' -- 'principalAttributeMap' property
- bean 'attributeRepository'

**Server logs**

```
    2014-09-25 16:59:45,516 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.authentication.LdapAuthenticationHandler] - <Found principal attribute: [displayName[James TAYLOR]]>
    2014-09-25 16:59:45,516 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.authentication.LdapAuthenticationHandler] - <Found principal attribute: [memberOf[CN=USERTOKEN,OU=GROUPS,OU=EGATE,DC=EGATE-T,DC=LOCAL, CN=ROLE_APP_NOTIFICA
    TION,OU=GROUPS,OU=EGATE,DC=EGATE-T,DC=LOCAL, CN=ROLE_CIR_AUTHORISER,OU=GROUPS,OU=EGATE,DC=EGATE-T,DC=LOCAL, CN=ROLE_APP_SANCTIONS_DB,OU=GROUPS,OU=EGATE,DC=EGATE-T,DC=LOCAL, CN=ROLE_APP_COLLEGES,OU=GRO
    UPS,OU=EGATE,DC=EGATE-T,DC=LOCAL, CN=ROLE_APP_CIR,OU=GROUPS,OU=EGATE,DC=EGATE-T,DC=LOCAL, CN=ROLE_CIR_EDITOR,OU=GROUPS,OU=EGATE,DC=EGATE-T,DC=LOCAL]]>
    2014-09-25 16:59:45,519 INFO [org.jasig.cas.authentication.PolicyBasedAuthenticationManager] - <LdapAuthenticationHandler successfully authenticated taylorj+password>
    2014-09-25 16:59:45,519 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.authentication.principal.PersonDirectoryPrincipalResolver] - <Attempting to resolve a principal...>
    2014-09-25 16:59:45,521 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.authentication.principal.PersonDirectoryPrincipalResolver] - <Creating SimplePrincipal for [taylorj]>
    2014-09-25 16:59:45,522 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.persondir.LdapPersonAttributeDao] - <Created seed map='{username=[taylorj]}' for uid='taylorj'>
    2014-09-25 16:59:45,522 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.persondir.LdapPersonAttributeDao] - <Adding attribute 'uid' with value '[taylorj]' to query builder 'null'>
    2014-09-25 16:59:45,522 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.persondir.LdapPersonAttributeDao] - <Constructed LDAP search query [sAMAccountName=taylorj]>
    2014-09-25 16:59:45,524 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.persondir.LdapPersonAttributeDao] - <Generated query builder '[org.ldaptive.SearchFilter@-1419023406::filter=sAMAccountName={0}, parameters={0=taylorj}]' f
    rom query Map {username=[taylorj]}.>
    2014-09-25 16:59:45,527 DEBUG [org.ldaptive.SearchOperation] - <execute request=[org.ldaptive.SearchRequest@1241774557::baseDn=dc=egate-t,dc=local, searchFilter=[org.ldaptive.SearchFilter@-1419023406:
    :filter=sAMAccountName={0}, parameters={0=taylorj}], returnAttributes=[], searchScope=null, timeLimit=0, sizeLimit=10, derefAliases=null, typesOnly=false, binaryAttributes=null, sortBehavior=UNORDERED
    , searchEntryHandlers=null, searchReferenceHandlers=null, controls=null, followReferrals=false, intermediateResponseHandlers=null] with connection=[org.ldaptive.DefaultConnectionFactory$DefaultConnect
    ion@511019109::config=[org.ldaptive.ConnectionConfig@1652971138::ldapUrl=ldap://eb2ts-app14, connectTimeout=3000, responseTimeout=-1, sslConfig=[org.ldaptive.ssl.SslConfig@1637458774::credentialConfig
    =[org.ldaptive.ssl.X509CredentialConfig@-421683437::trustCertificates=classpath:root_CA_base64.cer, authenticationCertificate=null, authenticationKey=null], trustManagers=null, enabledCipherSuites=nul
    l, enabledProtocols=null, handshakeCompletedListeners=null], useSSL=false, useStartTLS=false, connectionInitializer=null], providerConnectionFactory=[org.ldaptive.provider.jndi.JndiConnectionFactory@3
    99139047::connectionCount=1, environment={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory, com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.timeout=3000, java.naming.ldap.version=3}, providerConfig=[org.ldaptiv
    e.provider.jndi.JndiProviderConfig@1738533348::operationExceptionResultCodes=[PROTOCOL_ERROR, SERVER_DOWN], properties={}, connectionStrategy=DEFAULT, environment=null, tracePackets=null, removeDnUrls
    =true, searchIgnoreResultCodes=[TIME_LIMIT_EXCEEDED, SIZE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED, PARTIAL_RESULTS], sslSocketFactory=null, hostnameVerifier=null, controlProcessor=org.ldaptive.provider.ControlProcessor@33b4ac
    e2]], providerConnection=org.ldaptive.provider.jndi.JndiConnection@1ac243f3]>
    2014-09-25 16:59:45,540 DEBUG [org.ldaptive.SearchOperation] - <execute response=[org.ldaptive.Response@370759675::result=[[]], resultCode=SUCCESS, message=null, matchedDn=null, responseControls=null,
     referralURLs=[ldap://ForestDnsZones.EGATE-T.LOCAL/DC=ForestDnsZones,DC=EGATE-T,DC=LOCAL??base], messageId=-1] for request=[org.ldaptive.SearchRequest@1241774557::baseDn=dc=egate-t,dc=local, searchFil
    ter=[org.ldaptive.SearchFilter@-1419023406::filter=sAMAccountName={0}, parameters={0=taylorj}], returnAttributes=[], searchScope=null, timeLimit=0, sizeLimit=10, derefAliases=null, typesOnly=false, bi
    naryAttributes=null, sortBehavior=UNORDERED, searchEntryHandlers=null, searchReferenceHandlers=null, controls=null, followReferrals=false, intermediateResponseHandlers=null] with connection=[org.ldapt
    ive.DefaultConnectionFactory$DefaultConnection@511019109::config=[org.ldaptive.ConnectionConfig@1652971138::ldapUrl=ldap://eb2ts-app14, connectTimeout=3000, responseTimeout=-1, sslConfig=[org.ldaptive
    .ssl.SslConfig@1637458774::credentialConfig=[org.ldaptive.ssl.X509CredentialConfig@-421683437::trustCertificates=classpath:root_CA_base64.cer, authenticationCertificate=null, authenticationKey=null],
    trustManagers=null, enabledCipherSuites=null, enabledProtocols=null, handshakeCompletedListeners=null], useSSL=false, useStartTLS=false, connectionInitializer=null], providerConnectionFactory=[org.lda
    ptive.provider.jndi.JndiConnectionFactory@399139047::connectionCount=1, environment={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory, com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.timeout=3000, java.naming.l
    dap.version=3}, providerConfig=[org.ldaptive.provider.jndi.JndiProviderConfig@1738533348::operationExceptionResultCodes=[PROTOCOL_ERROR, SERVER_DOWN], properties={}, connectionStrategy=DEFAULT, enviro
    nment=null, tracePackets=null, removeDnUrls=true, searchIgnoreResultCodes=[TIME_LIMIT_EXCEEDED, SIZE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED, PARTIAL_RESULTS], sslSocketFactory=null, hostnameVerifier=null, controlProcessor=or
    g.ldaptive.provider.ControlProcessor@33b4ace2]], providerConnection=org.ldaptive.provider.jndi.JndiConnection@1ac243f3]>
    2014-09-25 16:59:45,546 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.authentication.PolicyBasedAuthenticationManager] - <org.jasig.cas.authentication.principal.PersonDirectoryPrincipalResolver@bf07ee0 resolved taylorj from t
    aylorj+password>
    2014-09-25 16:59:45,548 INFO [org.jasig.cas.authentication.PolicyBasedAuthenticationManager] - <Authenticated taylorj with credentials [taylorj+password].>
    2014-09-25 16:59:45,549 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.authentication.PolicyBasedAuthenticationManager] - <Attribute map for taylorj: {}>
    2014-09-25 16:59:45,549 INFO [org.perf4j.TimingLogger] - <start[1411660785397] time[151] tag[AUTHENTICATE]>
    2014-09-25 16:59:45,556 INFO [com.github.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager] - <Audit trail record BEGIN
```

**Spring Security config**

```
    <beans:bean id="casAuthenticationProvider"
        class="org.springframework.security.cas.authentication.CasAuthenticationProvider">
        <beans:property name="serviceProperties" ref="serviceProperties" />
        <beans:property name="ticketValidator" ref="ticketValidator" />
        <beans:property name="authenticationUserDetailsService" ref="ldapUserDetailsService" />
        <beans:property name="key" value="cas_auth_provider_ldap" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="ldapUserDetailsService"
      class="org.springframework.security.cas.userdetails.GrantedAuthorityFromAssertionAttributesUserDetailsService" >
      <beans:constructor-arg >
          <beans:list>
              <beans:value>authorities</beans:value>
          </beans:list>
      </beans:constructor-arg>
    </beans:bean>
```

**CAS deployerConfigContext.xml**

```
    <bean id="authenticationManager" class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.PolicyBasedAuthenticationManager">
        <constructor-arg>
            <map>
                <entry key-ref="ldapAuthenticationHandler" value-ref="primaryPrincipalResolver" />   
            </map>
        </constructor-arg>

        <property name="authenticationPolicy">
            <bean class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.AnyAuthenticationPolicy" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="ldapAuthenticationHandler"
          class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.LdapAuthenticationHandler"
          p:principalIdAttribute="sAMAccountName"
          c:authenticator-ref="authenticator">
        <property name="principalAttributeMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="displayName" value="displayName" />
                <entry key="mail" value="mail" />
                <entry key="memberOf" value="memberOf" />
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="primaryPrincipalResolver"
          class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.principal.PersonDirectoryPrincipalResolver" >
        <property name="attributeRepository" ref="attributeRepository" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="attributeRepository"
      class="org.jasig.cas.persondir.LdapPersonAttributeDao"
      p:connectionFactory-ref="pooledLdapConnectionFactory"
      p:baseDN="${ldap.baseDn}" p:searchControls-ref="searchControls" p:searchFilter="sAMAccountName={0}">

        <property name="queryAttributeMapping">
            <map>
                <entry key="username" value="uid" />
            </map>
        </property>
        <property name="resultAttributeMapping">
            <map>
                <entry key="uid" value="username" />
                <entry key="givenname" value="first_name" />
                <entry key="sn" value="last_name" />
                <entry key="mail" value="email" />
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="searchControls"
          class="javax.naming.directory.SearchControls"
          p:searchScope="2"
          p:countLimit="10" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending too much time to use the CAS feature to retrieve the roles and it did nt work...
So I decided to retrieve the needed LDAP attributes myself after successful login.
In my case I used Java, Spring framework, etc...

I have my class MyCasAuthenticationUserDetailsService that would looks like below and extends org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.AuthenticationUserDetailsService
And in initialiseAdditionalUserDetails() method I retrieve the needed attributes and set in my own CasUser class which extends org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User

```
        public class MyCasAuthenticationUserDetailsService implements AuthenticationUserDetailsService<Authentication> {

           @Override
            public UserDetails loadUserDetails(Authentication token) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
            sAMAccountName = token.getName();

            init();

            List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
            for (String role : getRoles()) {
                authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role));
            }

            CasUser user = new CasUser(sAMAccountName, NON_EXISTENT_PASSWORD_VALUE, authorities);

            // Sets additional user details
            user = initialiseAdditionalUserDetails(sAMAccountName, user);

            return user;
            }

              /**
             * Retrieves the user roles from LDAP
             * 
             * @return
             */
            private List<String> getRoles() {

            List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

            try {
                SearchResult searchResult = searchExecutor.search(connectionFactory, "(sAMAccountname=" + sAMAccountName + ")", "memberOf").getResult();
                LdapEntry entry = searchResult.getEntry();

                if (entry != null) {
                Collection<String> roles = entry.getAttribute().getStringValues();
                StringBuffer rolesCSV = new StringBuffer();

                for (String role : roles) {
                    int start = role.indexOf("=");
                    int end = role.indexOf(",");
                    rolesCSV.append(role.substring(start + 1, end));
                    rolesCSV.append(",");
                }
                String role = rolesCSV.deleteCharAt(rolesCSV.length() - 1).toString();
                String rolesArr[] = role.split(",");
                result = Arrays.asList(rolesArr);
                }

            } catch (LdapException e) {
                LOG.error(e);
            }

            return result;
            }


        /**
             * Initialise additional user details like country, ISO country code, email,
             * etc
             * 
             */
            private CasUser initialiseAdditionalUserDetails(String sAMAccountName, CasUser user) {
            try {
                SearchResult searchResult = searchExecutor.search(connectionFactory, "(sAMAccountname=" + sAMAccountName + ")", "c", "co", "mail",
                    "givenName", "sn", "displayName").getResult();
                LdapEntry entry = searchResult.getEntry();

                if (entry != null) {
                if (entry.getAttribute("givenName") != null) {
                    String firstName = entry.getAttribute("givenName").getStringValue();
                    user.setFirstName(firstName);
                }
                if (entry.getAttribute("sn") != null) {
                    String lastName = entry.getAttribute("sn").getStringValue();
                    user.setLastName(lastName);
                }
                if (entry.getAttribute("displayName") != null) {
                    String fullName = entry.getAttribute("displayName").getStringValue();
                    user.setFullName(fullName);
                }

                if (entry.getAttribute("c") != null) {
                    String isoCountryCode = entry.getAttribute("c").getStringValue();
                    user.setIsoCountryCode(isoCountryCode);
                }
                if (entry.getAttribute("co") != null) {
                    String country = entry.getAttribute("co").getStringValue();
                    user.setCountry(country);
                }
                if (entry.getAttribute("mail") != null) {
                    String email = entry.getAttribute("mail").getStringValue();
                    user.setEmail(email);
                }

                }

            } catch (LdapException e) {
                LOG.error(e);
            }

            return user;
            }
        }
```

And finally on the CAS Java clients .... I configure myCasAuthenticationUserDetailsService as below.....

```
        <beans:bean id="casAuthenticationProvider"
            class="org.springframework.security.cas.authentication.CasAuthenticationProvider">
            <beans:property name="serviceProperties" ref="serviceProperties" />
            <beans:property name="ticketValidator" ref="ticketValidator" />
            <beans:property name="authenticationUserDetailsService"
                ref="myCasAuthenticationUserDetailsService" />
            <beans:property name="key" value="notification" />
        </beans:bean>

        <beans:bean id="myCasAuthenticationUserDetailsService"
            class="com.jai.cas.MyCasAuthenticationUserDetailsService">
            <beans:property name="ldapUrl" value="${ldapUrl}" />
            <beans:property name="ldapAdminDn" value="${ldapAdminDn}" />
            <beans:property name="ldapAdminPwd" value="${ldapAdminPwd}" />
            <beans:property name="ldapUserBaseDn" value="${ldapUserBaseDn}" />
        </beans:bean>
```

This would retrieve all the needed attributes....