# CAS 4 - Spring security - Not able to set roles using - GrantedAuthorityFromAssertionAttributesUserDetailsService

Tags: java, spring-security, active-directory, cas

I am using CAS 4 - Spring Security - Active directory.

Have anyone able to successfully set the granted authorities from the roles retrieved after successful authentication ?

Internet searches suggest to use 'GrantedAuthorityFromAssertionAttributesUserDetailsService' which would set the granted authroites, but I am not able to.

I am releasing this variable 'role' using allowedAttributes in the service.
I am also able to retrieve the role from LDAP and assign it to the role variable. And the below code is suppose to set the granted authority to the SecurityContext but its not doing,

```
<beans:bean id="authenticationUserDetailsService"
  class="org.springframework.security.cas.userdetails.GrantedAuthorityFromAssertionAttributesUserDetailsService" >
  <beans:constructor-arg >
      <beans:array>
          <beans:value>role</beans:value>
      </beans:array>
  </beans:constructor-arg>
</beans:bean>
```

When try to check hasRoles('MY_ROLE'), I gets access denied 403 and it seems I am not able to set the retrieved roles on granted authorities.

**Server logs**

```
10:00:24,340 DEBUG http-bio-8443-exec-10 intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor:310 - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.cas.authentication.CasAuthenticationToken@e848bc56: Principal:
 org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@a4b4d0a7: Username: taylorj; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Not granted any authorities; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 10.100.20.125; Session
Id: 4652D17239607600EF2748E939F70BB0; Not granted any authorities Assertion: org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AssertionImpl@4a269585 Credentials (Service/Proxy Ticket): ST-1-tuVjcs2BP2UvyVUe50bZ-cas01.xxxx
```

Have anyone implemented this feature ?  Or is it a bug ?

Comment: check this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26656399/release-the-attribute-from-cas-to-spring-security

Comment: I have answered this in my another question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26054961/cas-4-not-able-to-retrieve-the-ldap-groups-after-successful-authentication